# How to databind DbContext SqlQuery() results in WPF

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to bind results returned from queries with dynamic where clauses to a WPF DataGrid.

Using Database.SqlQuery there seems to be no Load() method and no Local() to return an ObservableCollection.
Thus I am using New ObservableCollection(Of Product)(q1).
Is this the recommended usage, or am I missing something?

Using DbSet.SqlQuery I found no way to get at the data at all.
How is this supposed to be used?

```
Dim _dbc As New AdventureWorksEntities

''Using DbSet
'Dim q = _dbc.Product
'q.Load()
'Dim r = q.Local
'grd.ItemsSource = r

Const sql = "select * from production.product WHERE name LIKE 'fla%' and ProductNumber LIKE '%0'"
'Using Database.SqlQuery
Dim q1 = _dbc.Database.SqlQuery(Of Product)(sql)
Dim r1 = New ObservableCollection(Of Product)(q1)
grd.ItemsSource = r1

''Using DbSet.SqlQuery
'Dim q2 = _dbc.Product.SqlQuery(sql)
''Dim r2 = ???
''grd.ItemsSource = r2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you are looking for by doing the following.

```
' Load the products
_dbc.Products.SqlQuery(sql).ToList()

' Bind to all loaded products
grd.ItemsSource = _dbc.Products.Local
```

Also note that the results of `Database.SqlQuery()` are never tracked in the context so you will have to use `DbSet.SqlQuery()` if you want to bind to the results using `DbSet.Local`.

For more information on what `DbSet.Local` actually contains, please refer to [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Brice. I would never have thought of using to ToList() without using its result. I still do not understand why there is no Load() with SqlQuery. Obviously I am missing some fundamental concepts. Where is the documentation for these? In MSDN library there is only API reference information with lots of dead links. In the Data Develper Center I cant any overview info too.

Comment: As the [Load documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.load.aspx) says, it basically just calls ToList. It was added to make things a bit more obvious. I'm not sure why it's not on DbSqlQuery, feel free to [submit a feature request](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create). The main EF page is at [msdn.com/data/ef](http://msdn.com/data/ef) in particular, check out the Getting Started page.